# ASP.NET CORE MVC REACT APP: System.InvalidOperationException: The SPA default page middleware could not return the default page '/index.html'

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, iis, ldap, load-balancing

**UI PROJECT ENVIRONMENT**: ASP.NET CORE MVC

**UI PROJECT TYPE**: ASP.NET CORE + REACT APPLICATION

**ERROR NAME/ FORUM TITLE:**
ASP.NET CORE MVC REACT PROJECT: System.InvalidOperationException: SPA default page middleware failed to return default page '/index.html' because it was not found and no other middleware was processing the request

**ERROR DETAIL:**
I have a React project created with ASP.NET CORE MVC template.
This React UI project takes data from a separate ASP.NET CORE MVC based WEB API project and projects customer data to the screen.
Authentication, Authorization and Data retrieval operations are provided via API.
While connecting to a user UI page, LDAP authorizations are checked from the relevant API. UI page opens if LDAP authorization is available.
If the user does not have LDAP authorization, the screen will display You Are Not Authorized.
These React-based Web UI and Web API pages run on IIS on Windows server.
In addition, both UI and API are installed on three servers named S1, S2 and S3 and work over Load Balancer.
90% of users have direct access to the relevant UI. Some can log in from S1, some from S2, some from S3 server with Load Balancer management.
However, some users encounter the following error when opening the relevant UI page.
We detected this error on Dynatrace.

Error :
**REACT The SPA default page middleware could not return the default page '/index.html' because it was not found, and no other middleware handled the request. Your application is running in Production mode, so make sure it has been published, or that you have built your SPA manually. Alternatively you may wish to switch to the Development environment.**

We couldn't figure out why some users are getting this error even though most users access the same page.
What do you think could be the reasons for the access problem?

These React-based Web UI and Web API pages run on IIS on Windows server.
In addition, both UI and API are installed on three servers named S1, S2 and S3 and work over Load Balancer.
90% of users have direct access to the relevant UI. Some can log in from S1, some from S2, some from S3 server with Load Balancer management.
However, some users encounter the following error when opening the relevant UI page.

I expect for my React UI page to open for users with errors.

Comment: If this problem is related to LB configuration or IIS related configuration, then there should not be 90% of users working normally.

Comment: So my suggestion is to add FRT rules to all node servers, you could also enable FRT rules in LB server if you want. Then check the failed request. In addition, you can compare all the permission information of normal users and users who encounter errors.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the information. We run the publish folder in IIS by publishing the source code we have through Visual Studio.

The LDAP privileges of the users who get the error and the users who work correctly are the same. The authorization from the API is already successful. However, when opening the React page, I get the 'default index.html' error that I mentioned above.

What do you think is the problem? Could it be a firewall , could it be caused by login methods like VPN or Horizon ?

Comment: Pls open development tools on browser by pressing F12, and provide more details for us, by the way the faileld request tracing files will help us find more details.

Comment: I entered the browser's network area via f12.

Here, HTTP 500 Internal Server Error is returned for the favicon.ico file. However, this error returns for the user who has successfully logged in.

In addition, the following error is returned for a failed user.

Error : The SPA default page middleware could not return the default page '/index.html' because it was not found, and no other middleware handled the request. Your application is running in Production mode, so make sure it has been published, or that you hav

Answer (score 0):

I think I already know why.

Your three node server environment, the value of ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT may be `Development` and some `Production`, so the Development node server are running normally.

**How to check it?**

You can check your ApplicationHost.config file, or check [this blog](https://ifyoudo.net/how-to-setup-aspnetcore_environment-variable-on-an-iis-website).

**Solution**

1. Make sure your node server is Production.
2. Use [PublishRunWebpack](https://gist.github.com/ShawInnes/9b9b0e67007a2b16b070d390890d5c6a) to [deploy react project into wwwroot](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/issues/7135)

Comment: First of all, thank you for your response.

My application works with load balancer logic on 3 different servers.

Some of the users access the relevant site via VPN, some via VDI.

Users connecting via VPN can access the site, while users connecting via VDI cannot access the application and the page remains on the white screen.

What do you think might cause such a problem?

Comment: @srhnylmz This problem seems to be related to VDI. You can analyze it by capturing network traces. One is to capture the normal use of VPN to access the node server, and the other is to use VDI.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This week, we had users with both VPN and VDI connections tested.
More than 80 percent of users connected via VPN gained access. However, there are users who cannot access the VPN.
Users connected via VDI have not yet accessed.

What kind of monitoring method do you think we should try here?
We couldn't extract anything from the application logs.
Does it make sense to go with network packets or will packet monitoring programs such as Dynatrace or Wireshark benefit us?